# Getting npgsql and ASP.NET to work with postgresql

Tags: asp.net, postgresql, npgsql

We have several sites that run on ASP.NET and connect to a postgresql database. I am trying to upgrade our postgresql to 15 and to do this I have to also upgrade npgqsl. I have tried this on two different computers and I always get stuck with the same error.

> Reference required to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' containing the base class 'System.Data.Common.DbConnection'. Add one to your project.

I have tried every solution that I can find on the net, adding the reference to the web.config, adding a reference to the solution manually, but I cannot get past this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried to add this reference manually to the `web.config` and also to the solution with no luck.